# What is the pool of characters used in a BCRYPT hash

Tags: php, bcrypt

> I was looking for answers on BCRYPT specific resources but found the anwser within PHP's documentation for `crypt`.

I have an issue whereby I need to do some REGEX to clean a BCRYPT hash (generated by [PHP `password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function using `PASSWORD_BCRYPT`). I want to be able to know the characters that could theoretically appear in the BCRYPT hash so that REGEX can remove all *other* characters from a string.

I have read [all about](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-in-action-understanding-bcrypt/) [various](https://clerk.dev/blog/bcrypt-hashing-authentication-encryption) bits of BCrypt, it's history and its development but I have not come across anywhere that states for canon what a BCRYPT hash can contain.

Current understanding is:

`*`, `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `$`, `.` `\`

Does BCRYPT contain *any* ascii character? (edit: no) I see it contains many but going through the many BCRYPT hashes I can find is not a good methodology for being sure. For example, BCRYPT hash does *NOT* seem to contain `=` or `¬` or a few other characters that, *-for want of a better description-* have small UTF-8 definitions.

This is using a PHP interface if that changes how BCRYPT outputs hashes.

Comment: @apokryfos I have updated my question, the resultant hash is generated by PHP Password Hash function ; https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php . Ahh and I see the answer on the PHP Crypt function page.

Comment: The crucial thing to understand here is that *the hash itself* is a string of bits, not characters of any sort. What you need to find (and apparently did) is how that hash is *encoded*, which includes both converting to printable characters (e.g. as hexadecimal or with base64) and adding additional information (e.g. an indicator of which algorithm was used, the random salt, and any additional input parameters which need to be repeated to match the hash later). That's why the PHP docs were the right place to look: this isn't just a bcrypt hash, it's *PHP's encoding* of a bcrypt hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on the [PHP Crypt Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) page:

> CRYPT_BLOWFISH - Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z". Using characters outside of this range in the salt will cause crypt() to return a zero-length string

So this PHP/BCRYPT Hash will use characters from:

`$./0-9A-Za-z` range.

Comment: I have the regex as `^\$[\$\.\/A-Za-z0-9]+$`  Would you agree?

Comment: @dewd yes that looks correct to me.

Comment: @dewd a slightly better methodology may be: `^\$2y\$[\$\.\/A-Za-z0-9]+$` which ensures the string starts with `$2y$` and so avoids the insecure "$2x" or "$2a"

Comment: I also do a strlen check for 60 chars.